# Does the Forest Dweller's Shield have a unique ability?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Forest Dweller's weapons (sword and spear) have this description:

> bursting materials attached to the tip can be reused again and again.

This means that items such as elemental fruits and chuchu jellies, puffshrooms, and other items that would normally be one-time uses are given a cooldown instead of being destroyed.

Does the Forest Dweller's Shield have a special ability, too, if I fuse something on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only shields with special traits are the zonaite shields, with the energy-consumption reduction. Some shields (like the Lynel ones) do damage when you parry an enemy, but this is a trait that all shields can gain through Fuse.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't have any special ability like the weapons.

Comment: Ok well, that's sad